# Divide by two while loop in java

Tags: java, while-loop, integer-division

what I'm trying to do is use a while loop to check userNum % 2 > 1 once it hits one i want it to stop and print out all the values of the division so for example

if 20 is user num it would generate. 20 / 2 and 10/ 2 and 5/2 and then 2/2 resulting in 1 and then stopping 
(integer division)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DivideByTwoLoop {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      int userNum = 0;

      userNum = 20;

      while ( (userNum % 2) > 1){
         userNum = userNum / 2;
         System.out.println(userNum );
      }

      System.out.println("");

      return;
   }
}
```

thats what I have so far. 
any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And your problem is what exactly?

Comment: `%` is modolu and not division which is `/`

Answer (score 6):

`userNum % 2` is **always** either 1 or 0, so the condition of the `while`-loop is never true. The condition should be `userNum > 1` instead of `(userNum % 2) > 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my issue now is that while my expected output is 20 10 5 2 1. im getting 20 10 4 2. for some reason. i have changed the loop to look like 

While ( userNum >1 ){
userNum = userNum /2
System.out.print(userNum);

Comment: @Ibrahim i've tested the code. works fine for me (except for the missing 20 in the output). Is the code in the question the complete example?

Comment: it was, but thanks I actually ended up tinkering with it later on after I replied and got it to work, thanks for your assistance though!